# XSS: Does src attribute alone in img tag cause XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Below `img` tag contains only `src` attribute. Will it cause `xss`, without having other  attributes like  window events `onerror = eval(src)`?

```
<img src=javascript:alert('XSS')>
```

Comment: Modern browsers are likely not going to execute that specific code, no. But the real question should rather be, how that would have gotten there in the first place. If _any_ of this is user input, then it can easily lead into trouble if not handled properly. But before you ask any more questions about such specific details, you should probably go read up on the topic as a whole. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) is a good starting point.

Comment: @CBroe: I asked this question after reading above xss blog only. Currently I am handling  html user inputs, and I removed all the windows events in the img tag and allowed only src, height, width and alt only. Now my doubt is how keeping src attribute alone causes XSS

Comment: It causes XSS, if you don't handle what you put into it properly. Your example above did not even have the value properly quoted, but even if you had `<img src="???">` in your template, and the `???` was the part you would be replacing with a value I was able to feed int your script from the outside - then what do you imagine happens if that value is `foo.jpg" onclick="alert('bar')`?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the JavaScript won't be executed, you don't have to be worried about XSS.

It would be a problem if you used the value from frontend in backend.

**Example:**

```
<input type="text" name="age">
```

The user types: `<script>document.body.innerHTML = 'Hacked!';</script>`

Now in backend you simply use `echo $_POST['age']`.

So as you see, it is good that you care about your own code but be more careful about what the user could type, because that's the dangerous part!

In your case `<IMG SRC=javascript:alert('XSS')>` won't be executed. And even it it were executed, that's just something that YOU typed, not the user.

Comment: what if user enters some malacious javascript script referenced from other site like <img src= "http:abc.com\bbc.js"> will it execute? problem here is..no way we can validate the src if its valid or not?

Comment: @cpp_learner if it is a very old browser, yes. It would be a problem. But the modern browsers do not support it. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Script_in_IMG_tags ... as long as you don't save it in your database and don't use it in backend, even then it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This particular line of code in isolation: **No**.

Website that can be tricked to generate such line of code: **Probably yes**.

If your template is something like:

```
<img src=$user_data>
```

Then it is almost certainly vulnerable.

Even if you're trying to blacklist some "bad characters" in the submitted data, it may still be vulnerable. For example, even if you forbid spaces, it's still possible to add extra attributes by taking advantage of error recovery from invalid markup:

```
<img src="foo"/onerror="baz">
```

The only certain solution, which is also relatively simple, is:

1. Escape the data you print in HTML. At minimum change `<` to `&lt;`, `"` to `&quot;`
2. Always quote attributes with dynamic data.